# Multidimensional array search to return master key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
$main_array= array(
"Key1" => array(1,2,14,15,16,17,18,19,22,45,47),
"Key2" => array(6,7,40,41,42,43,48,51,52),
"Key3" => array(4,5,8,46,49,53),
"Key4" => array(3,12,13,50),
"Key5" => array(0,9,10,11,20,23,44,),
"Key6" => array(21,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,55,56,57),
"Key7" => array(53)
);
```

Could you point me how can I get the KeyX value ?

Desired command $getKey(53) - 53 is in the Key7

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: tried use array_search but it failed

Comment: array_search only works on a one dimension array. For 2d, you would likely need to just foreach over the outer array and then you can array_search or in_array for the sub-array.

Comment: Sadly I can not visualize that myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
foreach ($main_array as $key => $value) {
    if(is_array($value) && array_search($search, $value) !== false) {
        return $key;
    }
}
```

Comment: return array_search($key, array_keys($main_array))+1; for getting the number also a nice idea:p